# Error while using Google API in Vue mounted hook

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js

Need assistance on this. I have the Google map api loaded on the created hook of the parent component. But I keep on getting this error Error in the created hook: `ReferenceError: google is not defined`

Below is how the Google map script was called.

```
mounted() {
    let mapScript = document.createElement('script');
    mapScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=TheKey');
    document.head.appendChild(mapScript);
}
```

And this is the child component where I want the Google map to be displayed.

```
<template>
<div>
    <div ref="mapID" :id="mapID"></div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: [ 'place', 'coordinates' ],
    data() {
        return {
            mapID: 'mapID',
            markerCord: '',
            markers: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        initialize() {
            console.log('Hello World');
            let locations = [
                ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
                ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
                ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
                ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
                ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
            ];

            let map = new 
            google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(this.mapID), {
                zoom: 10,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });

            let infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            let marker, i;

            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], 
                    locations[i][2]),
                    map: map
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', 
                (function(marker, i) {
                    return function() {
                        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, i));
            }
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.initialize()
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not the standard way of doing it.

I suggest you follow the best practice (installing a NPM package) as stated in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49291060/1850609

So, again, follow the steps above, it will save you from headaches in the long run.

That being said, here's a quick workaround for your case:

```js
mounted() {
  let initializeWhenGoogleIsAvailable = () => {
    if (google) { // test if google is available
      this.initialize(); // if it is, then initalize
    } else {
      setTimeout(initializeWhenGoogleIsAvailable, 100) // if it isn't, wait a bit and retry
    }
  };
  initializeWhenGoogleIsAvailable();
}
```

It will delay the call to `this.initialize()` until `google` is available in the global scope.

But, again, do the NPM way.